# “Functions are a first-class type” in swift?

Tags: swift, function, first-class-functions

the little knowledge , I have about first class function is that it supports passing functions as arguments and we can also return them as the values in another function ... I am very new in Swift programming language can anyone please elaborate it with an example.

Comment: You'll want to read the [Function Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_270) section in Apple's Swift book.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A very simple example to demonstrate this behaviour:

```
func functionA() {
    println("Hello by functionA")
}

func executeFunction(function: () -> ()) {
    function()
}

executeFunction(functionA)
```

Comment: This example illustrated one of the properties of "First class function"  ..     Property is "Pass the function as a parameter to another function"

Answer (score 5):

First-Class functions are functions that can return another functions.
For instance:

```
func operate( operand: String) -> ((Double, Double) -> Double)?{

    func add(a: Double, b: Double) -> Double {
        return a + b
    }

    func min(a: Double, b: Double) -> Double{
        return a - b
    }

    func multi(a: Double, b: Double) -> Double {
        return a * b
    }

    func div (a: Double, b: Double) -> Double{
        return a / b
    }

    switch operand{
    case "+":
        return add
    case "-":
        return min
    case "*":
        return multi
    case "/":
        return div
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

The function `operate` returns a function that takes two double as its arguments and returns one double.

The usage of this function is:

```
var function = operate("+")
print(" 3 + 4 = \(function!(3,4))")

function = operate("-")
print(" 3 - 4 = \(function!(3,4))")

function = operate("*")
print(" 3 * 4 = \(function!(3,4))")

function = operate("/")
print(" 3 / 4 = \(function!(3,4))")
```

When you don't care about the implementation of a function, using First-Class functions to return *these* functions become beneficials. Plus, sometimes, you are not responsible to develop (or not authorised ) of the functions like `add`, `min`. So someone would develop a First-Class function to you that returns these functions and it is your responsibility to continue ....

Comment: Thanks for Detailed Explanation

Answer (score 1):

A function that returns a function while capturing a value from the lexical environment:

[image]

A function of an array of Comparables that returns a function of a test predicate that returns a function of a value that returns a Bool if the value is the extreme of the array under test.  (Currying)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Any programming language is said to have first-class-functions, when functions are treated like normal variables. That means a function can be passed as parameter to any other function, can be returned by any function and also can be assigned to any variable.

i.e., (Referring apple's examples)

**Passing function as parameter**

```
func hasAnyMatches(list: [Int], condition: (Int) -> Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in list {
        if condition(item) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

**Returning function**

```
func makeIncrementer() -> ((Int) -> Int) {
    func addOne(number: Int) -> Int {
        return 1 + number
    }
    return addOne
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Properties of First class function

1. A function is an instance of the Object type.
2. You can store the  function in a variable.
3. You can pass the function as a parameter to
   another function.
4. You can return the function from a function.
5. You can store them in data structures such as hash tables, lists, …

refer https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/first-class-functions-python/